# TCP Server,client not recieving message from Server

Tags: java, tcp

So I have a java TCP server and client.The client is trying to register a user to the server.I can see that the user is being added on the server from my print statement but my client is not recieving the "User was added,try logging in" message.

Server

```
class Server implements Runnable
{
Socket connectionSocket;
    UserRepo userRepo;
    public static final String COMMAND_SEPARATOR = "%%";

public Server(Socket s){
    try{
        System.out.println("Client Got Connected  " );
        connectionSocket=s;
                    userRepo = new UserRepo();
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

public void run(){
    try{

               String recievedMessage="";
            BufferedReader reader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter writer= 
                    new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream()));

                    while(!recievedMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
            recievedMessage = reader.readLine().trim();
                    String [] components = recievedMessage.split(COMMAND_SEPARATOR);
                    if(components[0].equals("register")){
                        User user= userRepo.addUser(components[1], components[2]);
                        if(user==null){
                            writer.write("\r\n=== User wasnt added,"
                                    + "mayby there is already an account for that email? " );
            writer.flush();
                        }else{
                                writer.write("\r\n=== User was added,try logging in");
                                System.out.println("user added");
            writer.flush();
                        }
                    }


            recievedMessage="";
                    recievedMessage = reader.readLine().trim();
                    }
            connectionSocket.close();
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

 public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
  {
     System.out.println("Threaded Server is Running  " );
     ServerSocket mysocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
     while(true)
     {
        Socket sock = mysocket.accept();
        Server server=new Server(sock);

        Thread serverThread=new Thread(server);
        serverThread.start();

     }
  }
 }
```

Client

```
    import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import java.net.Socket;
  import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;


     public class ClientShell {
   public static final String COMMAND_SEPARATOR = "%%";
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        User loggedInUser = null;
        String message = "";
        String response = null;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // 1) Build data socket for client to use
        Socket serverLink = new Socket("localhost", 5555);

        // 2) Set up streams
        // PrintWriter used for sending messages
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(serverLink.getOutputStream());
        // Scanner / BufferedReader used for receiving messages
        Scanner input = new Scanner(serverLink.getInputStream());

        // 3) While we want still want to exchange messages
        while(!message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
        {
            while(loggedInUser==null){
                notLoggedInOptions(keyboard,message,response,loggedInUser,output,input);
            }


        }
        // 8) Close the link to the server (the data socket)
        serverLink.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientShell.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static void notLoggedInOptions(Scanner keyboard,String message,String response,User loggedInUser,
                                PrintWriter output,Scanner input){
    System.out.println("Type login for login or register for register");
                message = keyboard.nextLine();
                if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("login")){

                }else if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("register")){
                    message="";
                    boolean validUserName = false;
                    while(validUserName == false){
                    System.out.println("Type the username you want as your prefix for your email");
                    System.out.println("It must be between 5 and 10 characters");
                    System.out.println("eg type mgraham if you want mgraham@danielhaughton@haughton.com");
                    message = keyboard.nextLine();
                    if(message.length()>4 && message.length()<11 == true){
                        validUserName = true;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("It must be between 5 and 10 characters try again" );
                    }
                    }
                    String username = message;
                    message="";
                    boolean validPassword = false;
                    while(validPassword == false){
                        System.out.println("Type the password you want");
                    System.out.println("It must be atleast 8 characterrs");
                    message = keyboard.nextLine();
                    if(message.length()> 7){
                        validPassword = true;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("It must be atleast 8 characterrs,try again");
                    }
                    }
                    String password = message;
                    System.out.println("username:" + username);
                    System.out.println("password:" + password);
                    output.println("register"+ COMMAND_SEPARATOR + username + COMMAND_SEPARATOR + password);
                    output.flush();
                    response = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(response);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Unsupported command!try again");
                }
   }

 }
```

`

My output on the client

Type login for login or register for register

register

Type the username you want as your prefix for your email

It must be between 5 and 10 characters

eg type mgraham if you want mgraham@danielhaughton@haughton.com

daniel

Type the password you want

It must be atleast 8 characterrs

hello12345

username:daniel

password:hello12345

**blank line is printed here**

Type login for login or register for register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, look at what your server sends back:

```
writer.write("\r\n=== User was added,try logging in");
```

So, it sends an empty line, followed by `=== User was added,try logging in`. So, since the client reads the next line, and the next line received is an empty line, the output is what you should expect.

If you expect the message to be printed, the server should use

```
writer.write("=== User was added,try logging in\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading lines but you aren't sending lines. You need a line terminator in each sent message.

NB You *must* check the result of `readLine()` for null before executing any other code.